# WPF Text Input Search ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am binding many integers to a ComboBox in WPF. I currently have it set to where the user can type text into the ComboBox. What I want is to prevent a user from typing a value that is not in the ComboBox Items? Is there a way to do this? Here is the code:

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
           TabIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ints}" 
           Text="{Binding Path=MySelection, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

For instance, say the ItemsSource include ints from 1-1000. If the user enters 1001, they shouldn't be able to proceed until they enter a correct value. Also, the ComboBox should show possible values as the user types (If the user hits a 1, show 10, if user presses 10, show 100 etc.) Is there a way to do this all inside XAML? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not just using a ListBox if you don't want them to add?

Comment: What property allows user to type in a list box?